# MySQL count should return 0, returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this MySQL query, seems pretty easy:

```
SELECT users.nick, users.id, COUNT(pm.id) AS pms 
FROM users LEFT JOIN pm ON users.id = pm.touser  
WHERE users.id = :id AND pm.read = 0
GROUP BY users.id
```

What I want to do here is simply count all the PMs that aren't read (doesn't have "1" in "read" col). If there are any, query works fine, but when there isn't any row meeting that condition, it returns nothing.

I spent the last hour looking for solution, but it seems really odd, that it works this way. It should only print "0" while echoing "pms".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```sql
SELECT users.nick, users.id, COUNT(pm.id) AS pms 
FROM users LEFT JOIN pm ON (users.id = pm.touser AND pm.read = 0)
WHERE users.id = :id
GROUP BY users.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT nick,id, COUNT(id) AS pms 
FROM users LEFT JOIN (Select touser as id from pm where read =0) as pms1  
WHERE id = :id GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the table order:

```
SELECT users.nick, users.id, COUNT(pm.id) AS pms 
FROM pm 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON users.id = pm.touser  
WHERE users.id = :id AND pm.read = 0
GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  users.nick, users.id, COUNT(pm.id) AS pms 
FROM    users
LEFT JOIN
        pm
ON      (pm.touser, pm.read) = (users.id, 0)
WHERE   users.id = :id
GROUP BY
        users.id
```

`pm.read = 0` should go to the `ON` clause.

`WHERE` clause filters out all `NULL` values resulting from the `pm` miss.